# Does every coset in a ring of integers contain a totally positive element?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$, let $\mathfrak m$ be an ideal in $\mathcal O_K$ and let $a \in \mathcal O_K$ such that $(a, \mathfrak m) = 1$.

Does there necessarily exist an $x \in a + \mathfrak m$ such that $x$ is totally positive? That is, for every real embedding $\sigma: \mathcal O_K \to \mathbb R$, $\sigma(x) > 0$.

Note that squares are always totally positive and therefore this is true whenever $a \in (\mathcal O_k/\mathfrak m)^2.$ This lets us assume that $(2, \mathfrak m) = 1$ by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: What is your definition when $K$ has no real embeddings?

Comment: The result you're looking for is called the strong approximation theorem.

Comment: Thanks, just to confirm the answer is positive right?